# Is it possible to change properties of a resource instantiated with StaticResource element in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

With this piece of XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Rectangle x:Key="rectangle" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="8" Fill="Red" />
</Window.Resources>

<StaticResource x:Name="r1" ResourceKey="rectangle" />
<StaticResource x:Name="r2" ResourceKey="rectangle" />
```

it is possible to assign a value to say, Margin property, to each instance independently by code:

```
r1.Margin = 2;
r2.Margin = 5;
```

Is it possible to do it directly in XAML? I tried:

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="rectangle" Margin="3"/>
```

but Margin is not a property of `StaticResource`...

**Rephrasing after the XY problem sensor fired (appropriately)!**

I want to draw rectangles with exactly the same properties except one, e.g. the margin or the color, in order to be able to change the shared properties centrally and still be able to provide specific properties in XAML. Can I use a resource like in my attempt?

**Adding my exact need and code as suggested by comments**

My exact need is to show the effect of setting different properties to some rectangle, i.e. changing `Rectangle.RenderTransformOrigin` and `Rectangle.RenderTransform` to compare effects. It's indeed to learn WPF, not for a production application. At the moment, I use a style (`rotated`) as I wasn't able to use a resource (this is the reason of my question above).

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="Transform Center" Height="400" Width="600">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="title" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="rotated" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="201" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="81" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="CadetBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="fixed" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Indigo" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige" Margin="5">
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource fixed}" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rotated}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource title}" Text="No rotation" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Beige" Margin="5">
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource fixed}" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rotated}">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransformOrigin>.5,.5</Rectangle.RenderTransformOrigin>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="20" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                   Style="{StaticResource title}"
                   Text="RenderTransformOrigin" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige" Margin="5">
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource fixed}" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rotated}">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="20" CenterX="100" CenterY="40" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource title}"
                   Text="RotateTransform Center" />

        <!-- The center coordinates relative to the Rectangle are the sum
             of both center coordinates, i.e. .5 + .5 = 1 (bottom-right corner) -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Beige" Margin="5">
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource fixed}" />
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource rotated}">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransformOrigin>.5,.5</Rectangle.RenderTransformOrigin>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="20" CenterX="100" CenterY="40" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                   Style="{StaticResource title}"
                   Text="Both" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: "each instance" is a misconception. Unless you explicitly set `x:Shared="False"`, resources are shared. So both r1 and r2 refer to the same Rectangle instance. This is why you typically do not declare UIElements as resources.

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. **What have you tried?** You can't set the resource object itself, since it's not shared and so a new instance is created for each place you use it. But you can always access the visual tree from code-behind and do what you want. **Not that you should.** You seem to have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's a lot more likely you should be using a template, and specifying the margin in a view model, bound to a property in the template.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I've tried `<StaticResource ResourceKey="rectangle" Margin="3"/>` as well as the object element syntax. Of course VS says `Margin` is not a property of `StaticResource`. My need is of this kind: Draw rectangles with same properties, except the margin or the color. So I wanted to define a resource.

Comment: I also think you should be templating here. If these are rectangles in a canvas then you could bind an observablecollection of viewmodels to the itemssource of an itemscontrol. The itemtemplate has the common properties set and the variable ones bound to properties in that viewmodel. But i'm just guessing here at what you're trying to achieve. Maybe just a style setting all the common properties.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks. I'm trying to optimize some experiments, e.g. [I'm experimenting combinations of rotation centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVORa.png), for each case I need the same rectangles, except a few properties that are experimented, In that specific use, it seems setting up a view-model is a bit oversized.

Comment: You may perhaps use a default Rectangle Style, which automatically applies to all Rectangles you instantiate in your application.

Comment: @Clemens: That's a possibility, yes. If I try to summarize the comments so far: As I was afraid, this is not possible to declare a resource and then change properties in XAML. Nevertheless the idea is not a good one, a template or a style is more appropriate and also more in the WPF mind.

Comment: Are you only ever going to have 4? Is this really just to experiment for yourself? Because cut paste and edit 4 times would be simple and why worry for an experiment. If you want to present this to someone else or elegance then a style sets the common stuff and then you just set what will vary on each of them seems clear and simple. Each only has the stuff that varies. You have two types of rectangle there so 2 styles and give em a key.

Comment: @Andy: I understand your point of view about going cut and paste, this is indeed what I did naturally in the first place. Now I'm at the second stage: Trying to improve the code and acquire new skills in WPF. As a side comment, my initial question was about XAML allowing or not to set additional properties to a resource-based object. We are far from the question (which is still unanswered), it seems some would prefer to answer *another* question and some would like to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does XAML allows to change a property of a resource when it is instantiated with `<StaticResource>`

Short answer: No.

The `StaticResource` markup extension simply references a resource based on a key. It can't change any properties of the resolved resource. You will have to set the properties of the resolved resource itself by for example casting the target property of the resource to a `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to draw rectangles with exactly the same properties except one, e.g. the margin or the color

That sounds like a style to me. In WPF, there are usually several different ways to accomplish the same thing, and this is no exception.

> it seems setting up a view-model is a bit oversized

Maybe. Maybe not. It's hard to say, as there aren't any other details in your question. That said, given the problem statement above, I'd agree it's certainly not *necessary*, and absent any other requirements, I don't see anything to be gained by using view models.

Even so, here's a code example that shows three different ways, two of which are based on view models and templates:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO58683029RectStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO58683029RectStyle"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel>
      <l:MainViewModel.Rectangle1>
        <l:RectangleViewModel Margin="2"/>
      </l:MainViewModel.Rectangle1>
      <l:MainViewModel.Rectangle2>
        <l:RectangleViewModel Margin="5"/>
      </l:MainViewModel.Rectangle2>
    </l:MainViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <p:Style TargetType="Rectangle">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="8"/>
      <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </p:Style>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:RectangleViewModel}">
      <Rectangle Width="20" Height="8" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding Margin}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <x:Array x:Key="rectangleArray1" Type="{x:Type l:RectangleViewModel}">
      <l:RectangleViewModel Margin="2"/>
      <l:RectangleViewModel Margin="5"/>
    </x:Array>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <!-- Uses style -->
    <Rectangle/>
    <Rectangle Margin="2"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="5"/>
    <!-- Uses view models, individual properties -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Rectangle1}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Rectangle2}"/>
    <!-- Uses view models, collection -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource rectangleArray1}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The view model approaches rely on these classes (they don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because there's no need in this simple example):

```cs
class RectangleViewModel
{
    public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
}

class MainViewModel
{
    public RectangleViewModel Rectangle1 { get; set; }
    public RectangleViewModel Rectangle2 { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in the case of the style-based approach, a single `<Style/>` element in the resource dictionary can be used to define the default values for any properties you like. Then you can explicitly use a `<Rectangle/>` element where you want it in the content of your window, setting any other property explicitly. You can even override properties that were set in the style, if that's needed for any reason.

Note that in the above, the data template explicitly sets its property values. But you can actually combine the two techniques, by referring to the style resource when you declare the template, like so:

```xml
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:RectangleViewModel}">
    <Rectangle Margin="{Binding Margin}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Rectangle}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

As noted in the comments, declaring concrete UI elements as resources is generally the *wrong* way to do something in WPF. I hesitate to say it's *always* wrong, but I would say it's *almost* always wrong. Concrete UI elements should be declared as actual content in the XAML, with styles used to provide default formatting for those elements. Otherwise you should be using templates, and allow WPF to create the UI elements as needed, based on the template you provide.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a solution. At the moment I have used the style approach (and posted my code in the question to be more precise about my context). This is satisfactory and simple. What about the initial question? Does XAML allows to change a property of a resource when it is instantiated with `<StaticResource>`?

Comment: _"Does XAML allows to change a property of a resource..."_ -- if you are asking whether, strictly in XAML, you can modify the property of a `<StaticResource/>` element at its point of usage, then: no. That's not supported in XAML. Property assignment occurs via XML attributes, and there are no attributes valid for `<StaticResource/>` that would set the property value of the underlying object.